# Accidentally deleted a System variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables

So I wanted to add python to my system variables and it didn't work so I deleted the variable and accidentally deleted another one too. I don't know which one it is tho.
I do have an open console with the old variables, because python is still in there.
But the list I get when typing `set` is way longer that the ones I see in the windows editor.

How can I get the lost one back?
Thanks!

EDIT: its not the python one I lost, the unknown one!

Comment: If you deleted path in Advanced System Properties, Environment variables, then it is gone (not recoverable). Look at this article to see if you can reconstruct the path  https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: Saw your edit. No matter, the path is gone so you will have to watch for what fails and then try to reconstruct the path.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by restoring a backup that was made when I installed an application the day before.
The thread that was posted here had a comment that worked for me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139510/15226209

Answer (score -1):

Refreshing/Restoring your PC is the only way to get it back. You can follow the steps provided here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015759/how-to-recover-deleted-environment-variables